# Unable to set initial custom date with Angular Moment Picker without validation tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-moment-picker

I am using the Angular Moment Picker library and trying to set a custom date in the input field whilst also trying to prevent the user from selecting a date in the past.

My element looks like so:

```
<input class="form-control"
    moment-picker="endTimePicker"
    name="campaignEndDate"
    locale="en"
    format="MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm A"
    today="true"
    start-view="month"
    min-date="minDate"
    ng-model="endTime"
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
    ng-required="!campaign.NeverEnds"
    style="width: 60%;"/>
```

And my controller:

```
$scope.minDate = moment();
$scope.endTime = moment( $scope.campaign.EndTime );
```

When I open the form, the Angular Moment Picker shows today's date/time in the input field, even though `$scope.endTime` is showing a date in the past.

[image]

The only way I can seem to get the correct date showing in the input field is to set `validate="false"` on the element, but then the control doesn't pass validation because the date is a date in the past.

What I am trying to achieve is to show an initial date `(2020-07-29 02:14:00)` when the user opens the form, but if they try and change the `endTime`, then cannot select a new date in the past.

Is this achievable somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after playing around with this some more, and going back over the documentation, I found the best approach to achieve what I wanted was to implement a `selectable` method:

[angular-moment-picker#methods](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker#methods)

I removed the `min-date="minDate"` which allowed the Moment Picker to then show the correct date in the input field and then added a `selectable="isSelectable( date )"` to the element to filter out and disable any previous days:

```
$scope.isSelectable = function( date ) {

    // Disable all previous days
    return date >= moment();

};
```